# PHP, scope resolution with variable passed

Tags: php, symfony1

```
$columnToChange = $this->getColumnName($questionNo); //Gets EXAMHIST_Q2_JUGDGE
    $conn = Propel::getConnection(ExamHistoryPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
        //Update the approriate question with user answer in exam history table;
        $selectCriteria = new Criteria();   
        $selectCriteria->add(ExamHistoryPeer::EXAM_HISTORY_ID, $examHist->getExamHistoryId());
        $updateCriteria = new Criteria();   
        //This shows fatal error
        $updateCriteria->add(ExamHistoryPeer::$columnToChange, $userAnswer); 
        //$updateCriteria->add(ExamHistoryPeer::EXAMHIST_Q2_JUGDGE, $userAnswer); //This works
        BasePeer::doUpdate($selectCriteria, $updateCriteria, $conn);
```

***Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: ExamHistoryPeer::$columnToChange***

Can any of you guys, please tell me why can not this works, and how to make it work with 
*ExamHistoryPeer::$columnToChange*

Answer (score 1):

PHP is thinking that you want to get static property not constant. It's because of `$` sign in `ExamHistoryPeer::$columnToChange`.

Instead use `constant('ExamHistoryPeer::columnToChange')` to get values of that constant.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do this ?

```
$oReflection = new ReflectionClass(ExamHistoryPeer);

//Value of the Constant
$mValue = $oReflection->getConstant($columnToChange);
```